# How to limit export formats in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

For Crystal reports for visual studio .net 2005, you can export the report 
to various file format such as pdf, excel, word, rpt etc. If I just want to 
limit the user see only excel and word format and set the default file 
format to excel, is there a way to do it? Sometimes too many choose is 
not good, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention whether you are using C# / VB.NET or Web/WinForms.

**C#**

I don't think this is possible. You would have to implement your own Export Button.

Something along the lines of this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288404%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

**C#**

```
// Declare variables and get the export options.
ExportOptions exportOpts = new ExportOptions();
ExcelFormatOptions excelFormatOpts = new ExcelFormatOptions ();
DiskFileDestinationOptions diskOpts = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
exportOpts = Report.ExportOptions;

// Set the excel format options.
excelFormatOpts.ExcelUseConstantColumnWidth = true;
exportOpts.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.Excel;
exportOpts.FormatOptions = excelFormatOpts;

// Set the disk file options and export.
exportOpts.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
diskOpts.DiskFileName = fileName;
exportOpts.DestinationOptions = diskOpts;

Report.Export ();
```

**VB.NET**

```
' Declare variables and get the export options.
Dim exportOpts As New ExportOptions()
Dim diskOpts As New DiskFileDestinationOptions()
Dim excelFormatOpts As New ExcelFormatOptions()
exportOpts = Report.ExportOptions

' Set the excel format options.
excelFormatOpts.ExcelTabHasColumnHeadings = true

exportOpts.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.Excel
exportOpts.FormatOptions = excelFormatOpts

' Set the export format.
exportOpts.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.Excel

exportOpts.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile

' Set the disk file options.
diskOpts.DiskFileName = fileName
exportOpts.DestinationOptions = diskOpts

Report.Export()
```

**VB.NET**

You used to be able to remove certain export DLLs from the client installation. i.e remove all apart from the Excel DLLs and then it would only display the export options as Excel

Comment: The other answer works for me without any other issue. I use C#.

Answer (score 9):

Using CRVS2010 , you can remove unwanted export Option.

A new feature of CRVS2010 is the ability to modify the available export formats from the viewer export button. The following C# sample code demonstrates how to set the CrystalReportViewer to export only to PDF and Excel file formats:

```
int exportFormatFlags = (int)(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ViewerExportFormats.PdfFormat | CrystalDecisions.Shared.ViewerExportFormats.ExcelFormat);
CrystalReportViewer1.AllowedExportFormats = exportFormatFlags;
```

For More Details Please refer below link..

http://scn.sap.com/community/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio/blog/2011/01/26/export-file-formats-for-sap-crystal-reports-for-vs-2010

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
    Dim formats As Integer
    formats = (CrystalDecisions.Shared.ViewerExportFormats.PdfFormat Or CrystalDecisions.Shared.ViewerExportFormats.XLSXFormat)

    CrystalReportViewer1.AllowedExportFormats = formats
```

Answer (score 2):

To disable Crystal Report Rpt format try this :

```
Dim formats As Integer
formats = (CrystalDecisions.Shared.ViewerExportFormats.AllFormats Xor CrystalDecisions.Shared.ViewerExportFormats.RptFormat)

CrystalReportViewer1.AllowedExportFormats = formats

Or Short Version :

CrystalReportViewer1.AllowedExportFormats = (CrystalDecisions.Shared.ViewerExportFormats.AllFormats Xor CrystalDecisions.Shared.ViewerExportFormats.RptFormat)
```

Comment: You've made my day. I was going to implement a custom export function through delegates (already done for the print button): not hard to do but they I've had to manage manually all the export options. Your solution is easier, just one-line code.